# How to add results from count() function in R to the original data frame according to the belonging column value?

Tags: r

I need to count how many cases per column value there are and then average another column that is grouped by the column value for which I used count() function in R. But when I use count() function all of the columns except the ones that I grouped the data by have disappeared. Does anyone know how can I either attach the given count() values to the original data frame according to the column values that I used to group the data or maybe directly count the cases per column value so that the rest of the data frame columns ( which where not used to group the data) don't disappear? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it's difficult to help you without a reproducible example.
Use the `dput` function and copy the result editing your question. Do that again with the result you get after grouping and counting. This will help us help you.
Also copy the code you use to group and count.

Comment: The question would be easier to answer if you post example code and example data. It sounds like you are using dplyr... are you using `count()` within a call to `summarize()`?  If so, try replacing summarize with `mutate()`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above it would be much better if you share a piece of your data so you will have better chances of getting your desired output. However if you want the result of `count` function to be added to your data set use `add_count` instead. I hope this example is what you had in mind:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~name,    ~gender,   ~runs,
  "Max",    "male",       10,
  "Sandra", "female",      1,
  "Susan",  "female",      4
)

df %>% 
  add_count(gender) %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  mutate(avg_runs = mean(runs))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   gender [2]
  name   gender  runs     n avg_runs
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
1 Max    male      10     1     10  
2 Sandra female     1     2      2.5
3 Susan  female     4     2      2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data set name is df and for output i am creating data set called new.

You can use plyr for this :

New <- ddply(df,.(column name),summarize,Count1= sum(column name== "value1", na.rm = T),Count2= sum(column name =="value2",na.rm= T),mean1= mean(count1,na.rm=T),mean2= mean(count2,na.rm=T))